# How to handle large upload files by different users at same time in bottle framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

I am using bottle framework, i am trying to accept large file upload where the data will be uploaded to database, the whole process is taking more than 30 seconds.

I don't want to user to wait till 30 seconds, so i am giving 202 accepted to front end and uploading the file to database with threading process, so how to give response after the process completes to different users simultaneously.

Comment: What is the bottleneck: from client to Bottle server, or from Bottle server to database?

Comment: Time out is there for 15 seconds, after time out the UI server will show internal server error

Comment: Same username, password  will be used by diff members in our team , all will upload diff files at a time and i want to show the results of the uploaded files to each individual separately, how to show the results separately???